# selecting specific fields during runtime from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do we select fields dynamically?

I've got a table `Table1`:

```
+----------+-------+----+
| Table1Id | x     | y  |
+==========+=======+====+
| 52       | alex  | aa |
+----------+-------+----+
| 43       | liza  | aa |
+----------+-------+----+
| 21       | harry | bb |
+----------+-------+----+
| 21       | harry | bb |
+----------+-------+----+
```

I'd like to join on this `Table2`:

```
+----------+----------+--------+------+
| Table2Id | Table1Id | aa     | bb   |
+==========+==========+========+======+
| 1        | 52       | red    | tall |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
| 2        | 43       | blue   | thin |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
| 3        | 21       | orange | fat  |
+----------+----------+--------+------+
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
+-------+-------+----+----------+
| xyzid | x     | y  | NewField |
+=======+=======+====+==========+
| 52    | alex  | aa | red      |
+-------+-------+----+----------+
| 43    | liza  | aa | blue     |
+-------+-------+----+----------+
| 21    | harry | bb | fat      |
+-------+-------+----+----------+
```

As you can see, `Table1` has data in the `y` column the exact field name to grab from `Table2`.

How do select specific fields from a table, where those fields are actually stored as data in another table?

Comment: With difficulty. SQL isn't a scripting language, you can't replace a column reference with a column's value. You should really be fixing your design here. Otherwise you'll need to be using `CASE` expressions. If your design is worse than the above lets on, and you have *lots* more columns in `Table2` then that's going to be a pretty large `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option which would be a bit more dynamic

- No need for the `CASE`.
- `table2` could have any number of columns.
- No need to convert columns to string or a common datatype.
- BUT ... I suspect a bit less performant than ***The Impalar***'s answer.

I should note that this is for 2017+.  Oddly enough, 2016 requires a  "`string literal`" for `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY`.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9597f2829b830a8c10932317e8d1dda)**

```
Select Distinct 
       xyzid = A.Table1Id
      ,A.x
      ,A.y
      ,NewField = JSON_VALUE(B.JS,'$.'+A.Y)
 From Table1 A
 Join ( Select [Table1Id]
              ,JS=(Select B1.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper)  
        From  Table2 B1 ) B
  on A.[Table1Id]=B.[Table1Id]
```

**Results**

[image]

**UPDATE - 2016 Version**

```
 Select xyzid = A.Table1Id
       ,A.x
       ,A.y
       ,NewField = (select max([Value]) from OpenJSON(B.JS) where [key]=A.Y collate database_default)
 From Table1 A
 Join ( Select [Table1Id]
              ,JS=(Select B1.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  )  
        From  Table2 B1 ) B
  on A.[Table1Id]=B.[Table1Id]
```

**2nd 2016 Approach  -- Perhaps slightly more performant  [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=afb0c23e0af7e7ef588aa18723348836)**

```
 Select xyzid = A.Table1Id
       ,A.x
       ,A.y
       ,NewField = B.Value
 From Table1 A
 Join (
         Select [Table1Id]
               ,[Key]
               ,Value
         From Table2 B1
         Cross Apply OpenJson((Select B1.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  ) ) 
      ) B
  on A.[Table1Id]=B.[Table1Id]
 and A.Y = B.[Key] collate database_default
```

Comment: thank you so much, does this mean this will not work for 2016?

Comment: @AlexGordon Regrettably no.   On my 2016, the macro substitution fails.  Even tried 2016 on dbFiddle.

Comment: @AlexGordon Added a 2016 version https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=70664e3971479bd29da33d42698ecb4a

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns dynamically using `CASE`, as in:

```
select
  a.Table1Id as xyzid,
  a.x,
  a.y,
  case
   when a.y = 'aa' then b.aa
   when a.y = 'bb' then b.bb
  end as NewField
from (select distinct * from table1) a
join table2 b on b.Table1Id = a.Table1Id
```

Result:

```
 xyzid  x      y   newfield 
 ------ ------ --- -------- 
 52     alex   aa  red      
 43     liza   aa  blue     
 21     harry  bb  fat
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mVDMR4GLjFquvDGbZuYLsW/0).